# How do i fix this viewing error in FL studio 21 running on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04, wine, winetricks

So I've gotten Fruity Loops 21 ( a digital audio workstation focused on music production ) to work on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS even though it runs natively to Windows/Mac. But one of the minor pet peeves I'm running into is that when I go to the Piano Roll tab while inside a project and then select the View subtab and enable the option "All Notes" under the Key Labels option the Piano Roll does not label the notes as intended. Effectively showing no difference between All notes and No notes. Does anyone see a possible fix for this?

```
Starting at 6:55:25 AM
64Bit addressing mode
3DNow! support: no
SSE    support: yes
SSE2   support: yes
SSE3   support: yes
SSSE3  support: yes
AVX    support: yes
Touchscreen not available
Main GUI scaling factor: 1 (system set to 96PPI)
Temporary folder for this session:
C:\users\blake\Temp\Image-Line\{D520CA5F-722F-4EF2-B52B-57C1E68AE523}\
FL Studio language: English (US)
Windows display language: en-US
---
Animation timer set to 16ms, vsync disabled
Browser caching took 216 milliseconds.
Mixer track map: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125
---
Mixer threading map rebuilt: 1 layer(s)
   Layer 1: 1 unit(s)
      Unit 1: track(s) 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125
---
Opening ASIO driver: FL Studio ASIO version 1
Buffer length: 512 frames
In/out latency: 2790/2898 frames
Time out: 21ms (926 frames)
---
Opening MIDI output devices
Opening MIDI input devices
Loading project: version 4.5.4
---
FL Studio 21 Trial v21.0.1 [build 3348]
Registered to: Trial version
ProcessFirstTimeStuff
Clear playlist and create new project
Mixer track map: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,0
---
Mixer threading map rebuilt: 2 layer(s)
   Layer 1: 1 unit(s)
      Unit 1: track(s) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125
   Layer 2: 1 unit(s)
      Unit 1: track(s) 0
---
Loading project: version 20.99.3000.3228
Locating file Basic 808 Kick.wav in user data folder
File Basic 808 Kick.wav could not be found in base folders, now starting a search in all extra folders
Sample not found: %FLStudioFactoryData%\Data\Patches\Packs\Legacy\Drums\Dance\Basic 808 Kick.wav
Locating file Basic 808 Clap.wav in user data folder
File Basic 808 Clap.wav could not be found in base folders, now starting a search in all extra folders
Sample not found: %FLStudioFactoryData%\Data\Patches\Packs\Legacy\Drums\Dance\Basic 808 Clap.wav
Locating file Basic 808 HiHat.wav in user data folder
File Basic 808 HiHat.wav could not be found in base folders, now starting a search in all extra folders
Sample not found: %FLStudioFactoryData%\Data\Patches\Packs\Legacy\Drums\Dance\Basic 808 HiHat.wav
Locating file Basic 808 Snare.wav in user data folder
File Basic 808 Snare.wav could not be found in base folders, now starting a search in all extra folders
Sample not found: %FLStudioFactoryData%\Data\Patches\Packs\Legacy\Drums\Dance\Basic 808 Snare.wav
---
Mixer track map: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,0
---
Mixer threading map rebuilt: 2 layer(s)
   Layer 1: 1 unit(s)
      Unit 1: track(s) 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125
   Layer 2: 1 unit(s)
      Unit 1: track(s) 0
---
Startup took 5900 milliseconds.
The application was started as an elevated process.
```